# Service is injected but results in null pointer exception when its property is used. What can be the probable reason?

Tags: elasticsearch, grails

I have created a java service/file in src directory of my grails project and I have defined in within the beans in resources.groovy.

```
beans = {
    elasticsearchConfigManager(ElasticsearchConfigManager){}
    accounts(AccountsService){}
}
```

I am being able to inject this in one of my interceptors just by writing "def elasticsearchConfigManager" and use the injected java service's method without any exception.

Also, I am being able to inject it in one of my grails service. But in case of it, when I try to use a property of the injected class, I get Null Pointer Exception.

```
@Transactional    
Class AccountService{
     def elasticsearchConfigManager

        def index(params){
            def action=params.get("task")
            return this."${action}"(params)
        }

        def getAccountById(params){
            def indexName=params.get("service")
            def docId=params.get("accountId")
            try{
                GetResponse hit=elasticsearchConfigManager.elasticsearchClient.prepareGet(indexName, "_doc", docId).get()
    ....}
```

I get exception here: elasticsearchConfigManager.elasticsearchClient because elasticsearchConfigManager is considered to be null although it is injected (I can traverse to the service from Accounts service by clicking on the defined variable elasticsearchConfigManager and I can see injected symbol in Intellij).

However, when I inject in the following way, it works with no exception.

> def elasticsearchConfigManager= Holders.getGrailsApplication().getMainContext().getBean("elasticsearchConfigManager")

What can be the probable reason? I am just curious to know. Help will be appreciated! :)

Directory Structure:
[image]

Comment: Are you creating an instance of `AccountsService` using the `new` operator or letting Spring create the instance?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have defined it in resources.groovy and provided it some name so basically creating an instance myself. Like (in resources.groovy) I have : beans = {
    elasticsearchConfigManager(ElasticsearchConfigManager){}
    accounts(AccountsService){}
} and I am using the bean via accounts. Is it because of that?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following in your `resources.groovy`:

```
accounts(AccountsService){}
```

Grails services are added to the application context by default so normally you would not define that bean definition yourself.  Your bean there is called `accounts`.  By default a bean named `accountsService` will be created for your service (assuming it is defined under `grails-app/services/...`).  It is unclear why you are defining your own but if you really do want to do that, you probably want to configure it to be auto wired...

```
accounts(AccountsService){ bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
}
```

The `accountsService` bean that the framework is creating for you will already be configured for autowire by name.

Comment: I have defined the bean in resources.groovy with certain name since names different than the ones that grails auto-defines services with are needed to get beans. In my use case, bean needs to be selected based on the service name mentioned in user's json request hence defining the bean on my own in resources.groovy.

Comment: "In my use case, bean needs to be selected based on the service name mentioned in user's json request..." - That is a bad idea but that is separate from the question as asked.  The reason that the `elasticsearchConfigManager` property in the `accounts` bean is not being initialized is the bean is not being subjected to auto wire by name.  Using the code I describe above will address that.